# How to import .p7b file in trusted root certificate in ubuntu

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate with .p7b extension, How can i add this in Ubuntu. My code base is in JAVA and i tried installing it in ca-certificates but got no success. Do anyone have an idea how can i use it in Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am also facing same issue? how did you resolve it?